# How to analyze text in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nlp, linguistics, text-analysis

Looking for a way to analyze text for certain characteristics such as:

1. identify acronyms and titles (ICANN, Dr. Mr. Ph. D., etc)
2. jargon
3. reading level
4. adverbs and adjectives
5. correct grammar and punctuation
6. active and passive voice

I looked at [Stanford NLP library](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), but have no idea what they are talking about (probably because I don't have a degree in linguistics).

Is there a Ruby gem that will provide this kind of text analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) For abbreviations you could steal from here: https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter/blob/master/lib/pragmatic_segmenter/abbreviation.rb. As for acronyms the list could be endless, so it really depends on what you are trying to do. You could potentially try a regular expression to extract acronyms.

2.) Not sure, you'll have to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

3.) Use the [lingua](https://github.com/dbalatero/lingua) gem and check out this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/linguistic-analysis-with-lingua/).

4.) Check out [engtagger](https://github.com/yohasebe/engtagger), a Ruby Part-Of-Speech Tagger Library.

5.) I am not aware of any library that can automatically detect correct grammar / punctuation errors (as there would be many cases where there is no clear cut correct answer). I did however make a gem where a human can correct a sentence and the gem will automatically show the diff between the incorrect sentence and correct sentence including the number of errors, type of errors, etc. It is called [Chat Correct](https://github.com/diasks2/chat_correct).

6.) Check out the gem called [verbs](https://github.com/rossmeissl/verbs).

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful answer. It seems that I may need different tools for different characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may want to look at this introduction:

http://www.slideshare.net/TomCartwright/natual-language-processing-in-ruby

The final slide shows the suggetions for Text, Treat, Tokenizer, Punkt, and Chronic.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the linkparser gem. It analyzes whole sentences, you can for example, get the subject, the verb, adverbs and adjectives. I believe you can also identify acronyms and titles within a sentence with this gem.

https://github.com/ged/linkparser

This gem is a wrapper for a larger project, Link-grammar, lead by the Abiword team.

http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/

Indeed an interesting project.